# Can't import turtle on Mac OS Mojave (version 10.14.2)

Tags: python, python-3.7

Trying to simply import turtle to run some lines, but my macOS Mojave (version 10.14.2) can't run it.

```
Mac @ ~/Desktop - [master] $ python3 SquareSpiral1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SquareSpiral1.py", line 2, in <module>
    import turtle
  File "/Users/Mac/Desktop/turtle.py", line 1
    Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: macOS? Are you sure? That error message appears to reference a Windows build of Python.

Comment: Yep, I'm running this from my Macbook Pro Retina, though, maybe it's cuz I'm running this from Visual Studio Code?

Comment: No, that wouldn't explain it. Are you _really sure_ this is the exact error message you're seeing?

Comment: I amended the error message above. I also tried changing the import line from: 'from turtle import *' --> 'from turtle, import *' and it gave me a simpler error: '  File "SquareSpiral1.py", line 2
    from turtle, import *
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have somehow saved a file of Python *output* -- from a Windows computer! -- to a file named `turtle.py` on your desktop.

Delete or rename this file. It's conflicting with the `turtle` module built into Python.

Comment: Deleted that turtle.py file, and it worked! (It was a saved session from IDLE 3.7.2: "Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32")

Answer (score 1):

The turtle module provides turtle graphics primitives, in both object-oriented and procedure-oriented ways. Because it uses tkinter for the underlying graphics, it needs a version of Python installed with Tk support.

Also, try this.

```
from turtle import Turtle
```

Comment: When I import turtle into my Python 3.7.2 shell, it works, though this is not ideal for me.

Comment: Tried "from turtle import turtle", but giving me the same error message.

Comment: Does your installed python has Tk support? 
or check the name of the turtle file in src directory of turtle. 
It should be turtle.py

Comment: I tried 'brew install python3-tk' and got:

"Error: No available formula with the name "python3-tk"